# Product of the incomplete gamma function and a monomial

Tags: gamma-function

Let us consider the incomplete Gamma function to $a = \frac{1}{3}$
$$\gamma(x) = \int_0^x s^{-2/3}\exp(-s) \,ds.$$
I am interested in the function $f(t) = t^4 \gamma(t^3)$. A quick WolframAlpha search [from here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E4Gamma(1%2F3,%20x%5E3)) says that this function is in $L^\infty(0,\infty)$. I am currently investigating if this is really true. As it is $\lim_{t \to \infty} \gamma(t) = c>0$ for some constant $c$. I find it quite hard to believe that $\lim_{t \to \infty} \gamma(t) = 0$.

Comment: I've edited your post. Please ensure that it still represents what you originally intended.

Comment: To use the lower incomplete Gamma function, you need to introduce the additional middle argument as 0: [x^4Gamma(1/3, 0, x^3)](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E4Gamma(1%2F3,+0,+x%5E3))

Answer (score 2):

Wolfram's definition of the incomplete gamma function is as follows
$$\Gamma(a,z)=\int_z^\infty t^{a-1}e^{-t}\mathrm{d}t$$
What you meant to write was $\Gamma(1/3)-\Gamma(1/3,x^3)$ and the limit is indeed unbounded. See their reference here - https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Gamma.html

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up!